# Ionic v3: When using the Ionic Range, the ionic icon doesn't show up

Tags: ionic-framework

I employ an ionic range in my code with two icons at the beginning and the end. But these two icons didn't show up - only the range showed up. I have looked up their offcial document (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range) and here's my code (I basically copy their code):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range min="0" max="5" steps="1" pin="true" snaps="true" formControlName="rating"></ion-range>
  <ion-icon slot="start" size="small" name="sad"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon slot="end" name="happy" ></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Ionic document sometimes sucks and I really need someone to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add icons inside `ion-range` tag and for the left icon add `range-left` attribute to the `ion-icon` tag and for the right icon add `range-right` attribute the icon as below.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-range min="0" max="5" steps="1" pin="true" snaps="true" formControlName="rating">
      <ion-icon range-left size="small" name="sad"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="happy" ></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lnw4fo?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)